# Function overload/version choice based on input.

Tags: python, python-decorators

A quick question for all of the contributors. As an example, would it be possible, possibly through decorators etc. to achieve something like this?

```
if input == 'X': 
  #only use the 'X' versions 
elif input == 'Y' 
  #only use the 'Y' versions
else: # Error out


def printer():
  print("X")

def returner():
  print("X")

def printer():
  print("Y")

def returner():
  print("Y")
```

I have tried to define specific decorators that attaches to each function such as:

```
input = 'X'

try:
  if input == 'X': 
    def x(func):
      def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        func(*args, **kwargs)
      return wrapper
  elif input == 'Y': 
    def y(func):
      def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        func(*args, **kwargs)
      return wrapper
  else: # Error out
    pass
except NameError as e:
  pass

@x
def printer():
  print("X")

@x
def returner():
  print("X")

@y
def printer():
  print("Y")

@y
def returner():
  print("Y")
```

Any help/assistance would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just define the functions themselves in the `if` blocks:

```
if input == 'X': 
    def printer():
        print("X")

    def returner():
        print("X")
elif input == 'Y' 

    def printer():
      print("Y")

    def returner():
      print("Y")

else: # Error out]
```

In your original code, there were no "versions" of the functions; the Y versions replaced the X versions as soon as they are defined.

Or, you can define a function that makes `printer` and `returner` based on its input:

```
def maker(arg):
    if arg not in ["X", "Y"]:
        raise ValueError()

    def printer():
        print(arg)

    def returner():
        print(arg)

    return printer, returner

printer, returner = maker(input)
```

Comment: Correct, just putting them within an if/else comes the closest - however I wanted to have a cleaner solution - I'd rather not redefine very similar functions within an if statement. Would you know if there is any way to somehow 'mark' a version of the function, not using any internal function arguments? Hopefully what I am writing makes sense.

Comment: You can always use specific function names; define `printer_X` and `printer_Y`, then set `printer = printer_X` or `printer = printer_Y` as appropriate.

Comment: @pythonista what use case do you have for this? It almost seems like what you should be doing is an (abstract) base class and define a concrete X and Y and then create an instance or use the appropriate one otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, what you want is this:

```
def printer_x():
  print("X")

def returner_x():
  print("X")

def printer_y():
  print("Y")

def returner_y():
  print("Y")

dispatch_dict = {'X' : (printer_x,returner_x), 
                 'Y' : (printer_y, returner_y)}
```

now, you can do this:

```
printer,returner = dispatch_dict[input_val]
```